# Need help on arraylist bound (Homework)

Tags: java, arraylist

> Remove 2 beans from the bag.
>
> If:
>
> - They are both black return one of them to the bag and discard
>     the other.
> - One is black and the other white return the white bean to the bag
>     and discard the black bean
> - Both are white discard both and put a black bean in the bag
>
> What color is the last bean?
>
> You decide to write a program that you can run for 50 simulations. 
>   Start with a bag of 10 beans and continue running the program
>   incrementing the number of beans in the bag by one until you have
>   tested for a bag with 60 beans.  Fill the bag with random colors of
>   beans and with draw the beans from the bag on a random basis, as well.
>
> Run the simulation and print out four columns of numbers:
>
> 1. Number of beans
> 2. Number of Black Beans
> 3. Number of White Beans
> 4. Color of last bean.
>
> Use the ArrayList Class to implement this program.  Remove beans from
>   random positions within the array and add beans back in a different
>   random position

Here's What I have done so far:
but it keeps saying that the arraylist is out of bound. I know where the problem is but I don't know how to fix it. If I remove the plus 1 from the line

```
index1 = rand.nextInt(bag.size() + 1)
```

it would say negative bound error.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.Random;
public class Counter
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> bag = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Random rand = new Random();

        int color;
        int index1;
        int index2;
        int blackCount = 0;
        int whiteCount = 0;
        String last = "";

        System.out.println("Beans     Black     White     Last");

        for (int total = 10; total <= 60; total++)
        {
            for (int run = total; run > 0; run--)
            {
                // 1 black and 2 white
                color = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
                if (color == 1)
                {
                    blackCount++;
                }
                else if (color == 2)
                {
                    whiteCount++;
                }

                bag.add(rand.nextInt(bag.size() + 1), color);
            }

            System.out.print(total + "\t " + blackCount + "\t " + whiteCount + "\t ");     

            while (blackCount != 1 || whiteCount != 1)
            {
                index1 = rand.nextInt(bag.size());
                index2 = rand.nextInt(bag.size());


                if (bag.get(index1) == 1 && bag.get(index2) == 1)
                {
                    bag.remove(index2);
                    blackCount--;
                }
                else if (bag.get(index1) == 1 && bag.get(index2) == 2)
                {
                    bag.remove(index1);
                    blackCount--;
                }
                else if (bag.get(index1) == 2 && bag.get(index2) == 1)
                {
                    bag.remove(index2);
                    blackCount--;
                }
                else if (bag.get(index1) == 2 && bag.get(index2) == 2)
                {
                    bag.remove(index1);

                    index2 = rand.nextInt(bag.size());
                    while (bag.get(index2) == 1)
                    {
                        if (bag.get(index2) == 1)
                        {
                            index2 = rand.nextInt(bag.size());
                        }
                    }

                    bag.remove(index2);
                    bag.add(rand.nextInt(bag.size() + 1), 1);
                    blackCount++;
                    whiteCount -= 2;
                }
            }

            if (whiteCount == 1)
            {
                last = "White";
            }
            else 
            {
                last = "Black";
            }

            System.out.print(last + "\n");

            bag.clear();
            blackCount = 0;
            whiteCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is always so nice to see multiple people post the _exact same assignment_.  OK, first please read the javadocs on .nextInt(max). It returns between 0 (inclusive) and the max (exclusive). So size +1 will randomly return beyond the end of the array.

Comment: @KevinO then  that's a *duplicate* :D

Comment: @user8, except the particular way they are struggling with the assignment differs. I appreciate the attempt to help people learn, but it seems a lot of stackoverflow.com is now a homework solution site where people google the answer to paste into their work.

Comment: @KevinO Except that's their problem - they can't randomly select a value from the size of the ArrayList when that size is 0. So, they need to add 1 in the random call to make it cover a range of the right size, then subtract one from the parameter passed to add so it will insert in the right place.

Comment: @EdwardPeters, I do not follow your comment, sorry. If the bag (ArrayList) is empty, there is nothing to select from, so adding a +1 doesn't help: the array is empty. The larger problem, I think is not using zero based systems. Note using black = 1 and white = 2 rather than 0 and 1 (or better yet, enums).

Comment: @KevinO Nothing to "select from", but there is a position to "Add to". (Check out the docstrings on "add" and "get" - "add" will take an index up to and including the size of the array, i.e., the first empty position after all elements.)

Comment: @EdwardPeters, OK, the question was about the `index1 = rand.nextInt(bag.size() + 1)` line. The only place where the add is called (that I see looking probably too quickly through the code) uses the `bag.add(rand.nextInt(bag.size() + 1), 1)` call, which does not have to do with the specific question.  However, if the array is empty, you **cannot** do `bag.add(1, 1)`, so adding one to the random size if the array size is 0 will generate an error. It is wrong to use bag.size() + 1 without checking to see if the array is empty.

Comment: @KevinO Oh, oops, I was looking at a different rand call than the question. However, the `rand.nextInt(bag.size() + 1)` is still appropriate for the "add" call, since as you pointed out, the upper bound is exclusive. (`rand.nextInt(0)` will throw an error, `rand.nextInt(1)` will return 0).

Comment: @EdwardPeters, you are correct; I was editing something else simultaneously and mentally put the +1 on the wrong side of the parenthesis when I replied.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.